# if key, value pair exist in a dictionary skip python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two variables that I want to add to a dictionary using `collections.defaultdict(list)`
Here are the two variables:

```
score = [0, 5, 7, 7, 8, 7]
match = ['turtle', 'cat', 'horse', 'horse', 'dog', 'bear']
```

What I would like to do is to remove the key/value pairs that are already in the dictionary. Right now I am creating my dictionary using this method:

```
  scoring = collections.defaultdict(list)
  scoring[score].append(match)
```

However, this method gives me a dictionary like so:

```
dictionary = {0: ['turtle'], 5: ['cat'], 7: ['horse', 'horse', 'bear'], 8: ['dog']}
```

However, I only want horse to appear in the dictionary once. Is there anyway to prevent the additional of an identical key/value pair in a dictionary this way?

Comment: if you don't care about ordering you may use sets. Simply change defaultdict argument to `set` and method from `list.append` to `set.add`.

Comment: .... or use a second `defaultdict(set)` besides your `defaultdict(list)` to see what elements have already been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `set()` instead of a `list` for preserving the values:

```
>>> coring = defaultdict(set)
>>> for i,j in zip(score, match):
...     coring[i].add(j)
... 
>>> coring
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {0: set(['turtle']), 8: set(['dog']), 5: set(['cat']), 7: set(['horse', 'bear'])})
>>>
```

Since the `set` object doesn't preserve the order, if you care about the order of the items of the values, you can use an `OrdereDict` as the values container:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
>>> coring = defaultdict(OrderedDict)
>>> 
>>> for i,j in zip(score, match):
...     coring[i][j]=None
... 
>>> coring
defaultdict(<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, {0: OrderedDict([('turtle', None)]), 8: OrderedDict([('dog', None)]), 5: OrderedDict([('cat', None)]), 7: OrderedDict([('horse', None), ('bear', None)])})
>>> 
>>> coring[7]
OrderedDict([('horse', None), ('bear', None)])
>>> coring[7].keys()
['horse', 'bear']
```

Comment: What do you mean about order of the values? Does that mean there isn't a difference between `{7: ['horse', 'bear']}` and `{7: ['bear', 'horse']}`? Is so, that does not matter.

Comment: @interstellar I meant the items of the values. And if it's not important so you can simply use the first approach.

Comment: Okay. I think I get what you're saying. The order of the values does not matter and eventually I will sort the dictionary based on the keys anyways. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to keep using lists instead of sets, then do filtering:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in zip(score, match):
        if k not in d or v not in d[k]:
            d[k].append(v)


>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: ['turtle'], 8: ['dog'], 5: ['cat'], 7: ['horse', 'bear']})
```

Comment: I like your method as well. Thank you!

Comment: Sure @interstellar .. :)